# NameError: name 'ls' is not defined

Tags: python, command-line, nameerror

I am running Windows 7 and just installed Python 2.7.4 and all I get are SyntaxError:'s. For example when I type:

```
>>>ls
```

I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  file "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'ls' is not defined.
```

I am new to Python and have no idea what the problem is.
Math calculations work as well as code seems to work. It's just commands like `cd`, `ls`, `sudo apt-get update` (and `upgrade`). Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: what is `ls` supposed to be?

Comment: Why do you feel commands like `ls`, `cd`, `sudo apt-get update` and such should work in Python? *Those are not Python commands*, those are Linux commands.

Comment: You seem to have a Debian or Ubuntu Linux system confused with Python.

Comment: You can use `ls` in Windows (similar to Linux usage), but don't do this in Python.

Comment: Perhaps you'll like to try ipython http://ipython.org

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Root of my problem was that I was not asking the right question. I was trying to run scripts in the interactive-mode and entering 'ls' and 'dir' to see where I was in the directory. With everyone's guidance I finally found the part in the Docs about **Executable Python Scripts** that said Windows automatically associates the 'py' extension with python.exe. 
[here](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/interpreter.html#interactive-mode). Then it all came together in my head. I had associated the 'py' extension with my editor instead of python and that I should have been at the *Windows command prompt*.
Thanks for everyone's help and quick responses.

Answer (score 10):

I think it's unfortunate that you're being downvoted so heavily here. If you're new to programming, this can be an honest mistake to make since a lot of tutorials assume that you're already familiar with the command line.

The main problem you have (as others have pointed out) is distinguishing between the **operating system shell** (which is also known as the console, terminal, command line, or command prompt) and the **Python shell**.

The operating system shell/command prompt is one of the fundamental ways you can interact with your computer. When you open the command prompt, you run arbitrary programs by typing in their name, run commands such as `ls`, `sudo`, `cd`, and `apt-get`.

If you type in `python`, for example, it'll cause the command prompt to start the *Python shell*. From there, you can run all of the Python commands, as usual. However, this is an entirely separate program with an entirely separate set of rules. **The things you can do in the command prompt will not work in Python, and vice-versa.**

---

Now, another point of confusion is distinguishing between the **Windows** command prompt and the **Linux** command prompt. You can install and run Python in both, but certain commands (in particular, `sudo` and `apt-get`) are available only on Linux operating systems. Unfortunately, the rules for using the Windows command prompt and the Linux command prompt differ somewhat, meaning that some instructions you find will be applicable only in one kind of operating system.

---

So no wonder you're confused! You're trying to learn about Python, but a good number of tutorials/articles will mention this second, entirely different system with hardly a word of introduction, and expect you to already know how to use it.

If you're curious about learning more about using the command line, here's a good [crash course](http://cli.learncodethehardway.org/book) you can read. It'll teach you what you need to know for all 3 major operating systems (Windows, Linux, and Mac) and will hopefully make what you read online more clear.

Answer (score 2):

I see from your profile you are learning about Raspberry Pi. A Raspberry Pi can use Debian (or Ubuntu, which is based on Debian) as the Linux distribution. The commands you are trying in Python are **shell commands to run on that operating system**.

Python is another command you can run on Raspberry Pi, but that doesn't mean that installing Python on Windows gives you those other commands on Windows too. You have two entirely different things confused here.

Answer (score 1):

The answers above are correct, but they don't help you with your issue!

One solution that will work in Python is:

```
%ls
```

Comment: The answer is not clear. Please modify your answer and add some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

> it's just commands like cd, ls, sudo apt-get update (and upgrade). Any
>   guidance would be appreciated

Python doesn't support those commands. Those are operating system level commands, not python level commands.